# integral of a determinant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I had proved a little theorem, but I got disappointed after hearing that it 
is already known. The statement is:

"If $U$ is an open set in the plane, its boundary is a regular closed curve $\alpha$ and $\psi:\Omega\supset \overline{U}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is continuously differentiable, then

$\int_{U}\det[D\psi]\,dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\psi\circ\alpha}x\,dy-y\,dx. $"

Someone knows where to find it (book, paper,...)? I would like to read the proof.

Note: $\det[D\psi]$ can change of sign in $U$.

Comment: Isn't this just Green's theorem together with Jacobian change of variables?

Comment: Yes EuYu, it is.  It's Green's theorem after a change of variables has been applied into the image of $\phi$.  Don't be sad though user39490, if you came up with that independently, you can join the ranks of some famous people.

Comment: Surely I don't understand, I am slow, but is not change of variable applied only to $\det[D\psi]>0$ and $\psi$ injective?.

Comment: Short note: the integral in the right-hand side is not necessarily equal to the area of $\psi(U)$, since maybe $\psi$ is not injective.